# Fragment transitions in Android with MVVMCross

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross, fragment-transitions

In MVVMCross is easy to develop `Activity` transitions, but i'm finding so many troubles trying to develop this with fragments.

I got an application with a Hamburger Menu, and I wanna be capable to edit my own transitions between fragments. I've been searching in the internet but i cant find any solution.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity`as the base type for your activity you can override `OnBeforeFragmentChanging` method to set a custom transition animation.

```
public override void OnBeforeFragmentChanging(
    IMvxCachedFragmentInfo fragmentInfo, 
    Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    transaction.SetCustomAnimations(
        // Your entrance animation xml reference
        Resource.Animation.slide_in_from_right,
        // Your exit animation xml reference
        Resource.Animation.slide_out_to_left);

    base.OnBeforeFragmentChanging(fragmentInfo, transaction);
}
```

Comment: A quick note: To animate in reverse when fragments are popped from the stack, add 3rd and 4th arguments to `SetCustomAnimations` for `popEnter` and `popExit`, as in:

`transaction.SetCustomAnimations(
        Resource.Animation.slide_in_from_right,
        Resource.Animation.slide_out_to_left,
        Resource.Animation.slide_in_from_left,
        Resource.Animation.slide_out_to_right);`